# Launch AlertDialog from a DialogFragment in a different Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I have a rather complicated setup where a `DialogFragment implements Runnable` launches another Thread. I use a `Handler` to handle the results. In some cases it should build and launch an `AlertDialog`, but I couldn't find a way to pass the Context of the Activity that launched the `DialogFragment` to the Handler inside the `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Note 1:You can only show a AlertDialog from the UI-thread. Note 2: Inside a fragment e.g. DialogFragment you can call getActivity() to get a context

Comment: Thanks for the Note, but the Connection of those is my problem. Would the handler be located in a normal Activity I would simply use Activityname.this, that doesn't work with getActivity() as it raises a NullPointerException. I'm also unable to save the Context in advance :-X

Comment: I found a way: building the AlertDialog.Builder in advance in the Ui-Thread and then just calling show in the Handler in the DialogFragment. Not a perfect solution though.